# Moving Storage Spaces volumes between physical disks?

Tags: windows-8, storage-spaces

Can I move logical volumes between physical disks within the same Storage Pool? For example, if I have an HDD and an SSD in the same Storage Pool, how can I move a frequently-used volume into the SSD? And if I can, will the volume remain accessible during the move?

Comment: By using Storage Spaces you allow Windows to decide how to handle the data.  If you want tighter control of the data, and where it will be, don't use Storage Spaces.

Comment: But there are cases (like mine) where that automation isn't enough, and manual volume management would needlessly throw away the abstraction layer between physical and logical volumes. LVM on the Unix side serves the same purpose, and it allows manual moves between disks.

Ars Technica's article (http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/10/storage-spaces-explained-a-great-feature-when-it-works/2/) about Storage Spaces has an another scenario: Equalizing disk usage after adding a new drive so that parity volumes don't run out of usable space.

Comment: in regards to equalizing windows should be doing that itself.